# Problems while importing pyaudio

Tags: python, pycharm, pyaudio

I recently bought a new laptop , and i moved my files from my old laptop.
I was working on a project in pycharm which used the module pyaudio , i tried to run it and i got an error saying there is no module called pyaudio.

I ran "apt-get install python-pyaudio" , it was successful but the error persisted. 
Then i downloaded pyaudio from its website and installed the package.. the problem is still here , any ideas ?

Also , i changed the interpreter from 2.7 to 3 i , if thats any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PyCharm, go to `file > settings > project > project interpreter`

Select the python interpreter you want to use from the project interpreter dropdown.
[image]
Click on the green `+` button on the top left to add packages to the interpreter.

[image] 
On the search box, type in `PyAudio`.

Select the package you want from the list,

Specify the version you want,

click `install package`

> Note 
>  Install `virtualenv` if you want to set a virtual env as the
>   project interpreter. Else the changes will reset on PyCharm restart.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install PyAudio from [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads)

If you installed package for certain Python version, after changing interpreter in PyCharm it will not be accessible. So install for other version also. 
This should work